# iocp error, cannot receive message sometimes

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, iocp

**iocp code is below:**

```
void xIocpWorkThread::Execute(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    DWORD   dwNumberOfBytes = 0;
    ULONG_PTR   ulCompletionKey = 0;
    IOCP_UNIT   * pIocpunit = 0;
    DWORD last_err = 0;
    DWORD listener_addr = 0;
    DWORD listener_sock = 0;

    while( !xThread::IsTerminated() )
    {
        if( GetQueuedCompletionStatus(m_hIocp, &dwNumberOfBytes, &ulCompletionKey, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&pIocpunit, INFINITE ) )
        {
            pIocpunit->pUnit->OnComplete( dwNumberOfBytes, (DWORD)ulCompletionKey );

        }
        else
        {
            if( pIocpunit != NULL )
            {
                last_err = GetLastError();
                xEventListener *pListener = pIocpunit->pUnit->getEventListener();
                DWORD _puint_type = pIocpunit->pUnit->getType();
                pIocpunit->pUnit->OnComplete( 0, 0 );               

                if(pListener != 0)
                {
                    listener_addr = (DWORD)((void*)(pListener));
                    listener_sock = pListener->get_sock_fd();
                }           

                LOG("GetQueuedCompletionStatus返回false, errno = %u, addr = %u, type = %u, sockfd = %u", last_err, listener_addr, _puint_type, listener_sock);
            }
            else
            {               
                last_err = GetLastError();
                LOG("GetQueuedCompletionStatus返回false, pIocpunit = null, errno = %u", last_err);
                Sleep( 10 );
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

**the function above is running in a thread, different from the logic thread. normally, the error log would not be printed, but when game server is running sometime, It can't receive client message, and can't send message to client too, but after a while, the server will auto become normally, and can receive message, and can send message, when sometime is past, the server can't send message and receive message..... this happens periodically, the error log is below:**

2011-09-13 04:48:41 GetQueuedCompletionStatus返回false, errno = 64, addr = 227492836, type = 2, sockfd = 4294967295

2011-09-13 04:48:41 GetQueuedCompletionStatus返回false, errno = 64, addr = 227492836, type = 2, sockfd = 4294967295

2011-09-13 04:48:41 GetQueuedCompletionStatus返回false, errno = 64, addr = 227492836, type = 2, sockfd = 4294967295

*... many more of the same ...*

2011-09-13 04:48:41 GetQueuedCompletionStatus返回false, errno = 64, addr = 227492836, type = 2, sockfd = 4294967295

**the above is only a part of log file, as you can see, the error log is printed so much, error number is 64, and the socket descriptor is 4294967295(0xffffffff), when the error log is printed, the server can't send message, can't recieve message. I want to know how to resolve this problem, thanks to you!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [iocp error, cannot receive message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397816/iocp-error-cannot-receive-message)

Comment: @Icabcdefg, please edit your other question with more details rather than posting a new one.

Comment: Man, what the hell is that sleep in your code ? The concept of Overlapped IOCP is non blocking calls. Please check out at MS SDK samples on netds/winsock/iocp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Step one, work out what error = 64 is telling you. To do that open up WinError.h and do a search for 64 ...

The result is ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED - so, it's likely that your connection has gone away...

I'm not sure why you're getting so many of these, do you have a large number of pending operations on each socket?

The Sleep() is a really bad idea...

Comment: I don't understand "a large number of pending operations on each socket", what does it mean? , why do you say the sleep() is bad idea? by the way, "type = 2" in the log, stand for the send notification, but I want to know, why does the socket is 0xffffffff, and why does it produce so many log record..........

Comment: You will get that error return from GetQueuedCompletionStatus() once for each i/o operation that was pending at the point when the connection was broken. Since you say type 2 is a send operation then you obviously have a LOT of outstanding send operations that are all failing when the connection is broken. Ok, lets put this another way, why do you think the Sleep is needed here and how does it help your performance? I imagine the socket is 0xffffffff because you closed it somewhere and set it to this value...

Comment: thank you for you response, excuse me, maybe my english is poor, I'm from china, so I'm not good at english, I want to express what the error is, but not very clearly.
you say, the socket is 0xffffffff because I closed it somewhere, I want to know whether it is possible the client closed the socket, and the server didn't close it?  if the client close the socket, is it possibe the value become 0xffffffff?

Comment: The client closing the socket will cause a read to complete successfully with 0 bytes returned. The only way for your socket variable to become 0xffffffff is if YOU set it to it somewhere in your code. Note that you may be setting the socket to the symbolic constant `INVALID_SOCKET` which is 0xffffffff

Comment: but why does it produce so many log records? when invoke sending function, I add if statement, the code:  BOOL xClientObject::postSend( xIocpUnit * pIocpUnit, xPacket * pPacket )
{
 if(getSocketFd() == INVALID_SOCKET)
 {
  return FALSE;
 }

 return sendEx( (LPVOID)pPacket->getbuf(), pPacket->getsize(), 
  pIocpUnit->getOverlappedEx()->dwNumberOfBytes, 
  pIocpUnit->getOverlappedEx()->dwFlag,
  pIocpUnit->getOverlapped() );
}

Comment: the sendex function is:   BOOL xSocket::sendEx( LPVOID lpData, int nDatasize, DWORD &dwBytesSent, DWORD dwFlag, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped )
{
 WSABUF wsabuf;
 wsabuf.buf = (char*)lpData;
 wsabuf.len = nDatasize;

 if( WSASend( m_Socket, &wsabuf, 1, &dwBytesSent, dwFlag, lpOverlapped, NULL ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
 {
  int code = WSAGetLastError();
  if( code != WSA_IO_PENDING )
  {
   setError( code, "WSASend() 失败！" );
   return FALSE;
  }
 }
 return TRUE;
}

Comment: It probably generates one log record for each send that is outstanding. Does your server send a lot of data on each connection?